# Getting started with URL routing with PHP CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, url-routing

I just thought of routing my URLs which is like

`http://localhost/codeigniter_cup_myth/index.php/adminController/mainAccount`

and it would be pretty nice if it was

`http://localhost/codeigniter_cup_myth/Accounts/mainAccount`

Where should I start when routing URLs in my web application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also, adding something like:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|js|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

to your .htaccess file will get rid of the index.php part

Answer (score 3):

Routes are defined as such:

```
$route['product/:num'] = "catalog/product_lookup";
```

where `product` / `anynumber` is your URL: http://www.example.com/product/234. The second part is the controller/method. The URL we're talking about here would call the catalog controller's product_lookup method.

```
$route['accounts/mainaccount'] = "adminController/mainAccount"
```

Would fire what you're looking for. Take a look at the CodeIgniter [User Guide](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html) for more examples.

I use this `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Which allows any physically existing file to be accessed, all else is routed to CI.

Answer (score 1):

u can check woo url routing component

http://code.google.com/p/woo/

woo url routing  feature:

1. easy to add custom and dynamic routing url to route collection.
2. easy to create constraits which restrict URLs that match a paticure route.
3. supporting catchall style in the route match.
4. using route debugger to show routes match status in route collection when directly type URL address in the browser address bar.
5. creating custom route handler to process the URL that match a paticular route in the route collection.