# URL routing for this in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am starting a project in PHP with CodIgniter, and I have a project under `wamp/www/myproject`. When I start localhost and click on my project the [URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_locator) looks like this:

```
localhost/myproject
```

I want to have such routing that when someone come and type

```
localhost/myproject/box/123
```

he should be redirected to the `home` controller and `box` method.

How can I do it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2584571/getting-started-with-url-routing-with-php-codeigniter

Comment: @Eddy Freddy well i tried this but its not working

Comment: There is already a good example in the documentation.

Comment: Can you also post how the new uri should look like?

Comment: it should look like localhost/mediabox/box/1

Answer (score 3):

Go to the routes configuration file (I suppose you know where) and add this:

```
$route['box/(:num)'] = 'home/box/$1';
```

Anything that has `box/[any number]` will get routed to the `home/box` method, and the match to the `(:num)` as the first parameter.

So your

```
http://localhost/myproject/index.php/box/123
```

will get routed to: ("displayed as if you used")

```
http://localhost/myproject/index.php/home/box/123
```

(This I assume you didn't have rewrite engine remove `index.php` from the URL yet.)

---

[From the guide](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html):

> ***Removing the index.php file***
>
> By default, **the index.php file will be included in your URLs**:
>
> ```
> http://example.com/index.php/news/article/my_article
> ```
>
> You can easily remove this file by using a .htaccess file with some simple rules. Here is an example of such a file, using the "negative" method in which everything is redirected except the specified items:
>
> ```
> RewriteEngine on
> RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
> ```
>
> In the above example, any HTTP request other than those for index.php, images, and robots.txt is treated as a request for your index.php file.

Comment: I tried your suggested solution but when i type http://localhost/mediabox/box/1 in url it says the requested url not found on the server

Comment: are you using apache rewrite to remove `index.php/` or not yet? because if not, your site should be like `http://localhost/mediabox/index/box/1`

Comment: as far as this question is concerned, it's out of it's scope since you asked for CI routing and not url rewriting. however, it's found here: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html

Comment: but index.php is not included in my url when i type localhost/myproject

Comment: that's because `index.php` is the default file viewed when you visit a subfolder and not indicating a file. have you even tried visiting `http://localhost/mediabox/index.php/welcome` (the pre-packaged demo page)? please read the user guide.

Comment: if my controller name is box and the method is index can I create a url like localhost/myproject/box/id... I mean can I skip the method name?

Comment: you can't unless you use routing. besides, codeigniter will always treat the first segment as controller, and second as method. the rest are parameters.

Comment: So you mean I can do it using routing?